# How to deal with hadamard product of matrix with vector

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

$$Ax=b$$

$A$ is a real square symmetric matrix with all non-zero entries, $x$ and $b$ are vectors.

The hadamard inverse of $A$ is defined

$$A^{\circ-1} \circ A = E$$

where $E$ is a matrix of ones.

So, multiplying the LHS of the first equation by $A^{\circ-1}$ gives $Ex$. That much is pretty clear. But what happens when you multiply the RHS by $A^{\circ-1}$? The operation $A^{\circ-1}\circ b$ doesn't seem well defined since there is a dimension mismatch.

However, considering that $b=Ib$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, perhaps what you're supposed to do is

$$A^{\circ-1} \circ I b$$

But then you lose all the off diagonal elements of $A^{\circ-1}$ and you get

$$Ex=D_{A^{\circ-1}}b$$

(where $D_{A^{\circ-1}}$ is a diagonal matrix with the diagonal elements of $A^{\circ-1}$ and zeros elsewhere)

Which means

$$\sum_i x_i = A^{\circ-1}_{kk}b_k \:\:\: ; \:\: \forall k$$

So the elements of $b$ divided by the corresponding diagonal elements in $A$ have to be constant? That can't be right.

Comment: It doesn't sound right, because the diagonal elements of the Hadamard inverse would then be determined by both $A$ and by $b$ in a way that is likely to be infeasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what you're trying to do, but here's an idea for using a Hadamard product to solve the equation.

A Hadamard inverse (let's call it $q$) exists for the vector $b$, assuming that all elements are non-zero.
So we have the identity 
$$b\circ q = 1$$ 
Multiply both sides of the linear equation by this vector
$$\eqalign{
  q\circ(Ax) &= q\circ b = 1 \cr
  QAx &= 1 \cr
  x &= (QA)^{-1}\,1 \cr
}$$
where $$Q = {\rm Diag}(q)$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there some vector $z$ such that $z \circ (Ax) = A1$?

Comment: @ben That would be  $$z = (A1)\oslash b = B^{-1}A1$$ where $B={\rm Diag}(b)$